# Recylerview should overlap the background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Hi i want to design like below image where front is recylerview with grid and behind that there is another background .How to create this kind of layout.Currently i am using below code to achieve this kind of design but as i know its not good practice for different screen size.Is there another way to do this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="@color/white" />


    <include
        layout="@layout/recyclerview_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: use nested layout

Comment: can you please elaborate

Comment: `RecyclerView` extends `ViewGroup` which extends `View` so simply use `View#setBackground()` method

Comment: How it is looking with your changes?

Comment: its working as i want but i dont think its a right way to achieve this...it can be possible some time that grid item count can be less.

Comment: How about using a transparent background RecyclerView?

Comment: transparent bg ?how it will resolve ?can u explain please

Comment: Ok. From my understanding, you required one bg image overlapping with a white bg and on the top the recycler view rite.

Comment: yeah you are  right

Comment: Ok. Pls wait. I ll come back with an explained answer :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179382/discussion-between-santhosh-joseph-and-bunny).

Comment: create shape and set it to  main layout of xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the background to the RecyclerView either from layout xml or from activity source code.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
   android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
   android:background="@drawable/sample_drawable"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />
```

or

```
recyclerView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.sample_drawable)
```

Comment: please see the above  image ...there is another bg behind the grid.

Comment: That's the image you need to set to recycler's view backgroud.

Answer (score 0):

Design your parent layout like this :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white">

<!-- Main background which is to be replaced with your image-->
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/main_background"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

<!-- Sub view with white background -->
<View
    android:id="@+id/sub_background"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"/>

<!-- Background as Transparent-->
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also make your child item's background as transparent.

Hope this helps.